# Microsoft Dynamics REST API $filter parameter returning 400 error

Tags: rest, microsoft-dynamics

We are pulling the contacts from the Microsoft Dynamics system using the REST API. There are approx. 88K contacts and we would like to reduce the amount of data transferred by using a filter that checks the 'modifiedon' field. When we add the filter to the query, it’s returning a 400 response. We have tried to filter with several fields, we have tried to filter with the value with single ticks, and we have tried using double clicks to wrap the value.

### Request Without the $filter parameter

This query does **not** contain the $filter parameter and will return 5K of 88K contacts.

URL: `https://[HOST].api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts?$select=emailaddress1,fullname,nickname,telephone1,createdon,modifiedon,_parentcustomerid_value`

This will return 5K results with the next link allowing us to iterate all results in the database.

**Response**

```
(
    [@odata.etag] => *************
    [emailaddress1] => *************
    [fullname] => *************
    [nickname] => 
    [telephone1] => 
    [createdon] => 2018-12-18T22:17:23Z
    [modifiedon] => 2018-12-18T22:17:26Z
    [_parentcustomerid_value] => 
    [contactid] => *************
)
```

### Request With the $filter parameter

This query **does** contain the $filter parameter. When this is run, the dynamics returns a 400 error.

URL: `https://[HOST].api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts?$select=emailaddress1,fullname,nickname,telephone1,createdon,modifiedon,_parentcustomerid_value&$filter=modifiedon gt 2018-01-01`

**Response**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

#### Note: We've also tried these queries and get a 400 response

NOTE: The following attempts also return 400 errors:

https://[HOST].api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts?$filter=modifiedon gt '2018-01-01'

https://[HOST].api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts?$select=emailaddress1,fullname,nickname,telephone1,createdon,modifiedon,_parentcustomerid_value&$filter=modifiedon gt "2018-01-01"

https://[HOST].api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts?$select=emailaddress1,fullname,nickname,telephone1,createdon,modifiedon,_parentcustomerid_value&$filter=fullname ne null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and it came down to having spaces in the query which PHP and cURL was not encoding. Thanks to AnkUser for suggesting using a different tool to test.

This Works!

> $filter=modifiedon%20gt%20'2019-05-07'

This DOES NOT work.

> $filter=modifiedon gt '2019-05-07'

Answer (score 0):

I created a Trial Instance and tired calling Webapi using Postman and I was able to filter Records.

```
 https://[host].api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts?$select=fullname&$filter=modifiedon gt '2019-05-13'

    Result

    "value": [
            {
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"1732225\"",
                "fullname": "test contact",
                "contactid": "9fb24443-1476-e911-a975-000d3ab0fc6e"
            }


    https://[host].api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts?$select=fullname&$filter=fullname ne null

    Result

     "value": [
            {
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"1732225\"",
                "fullname": "test contact",
                "contactid": "9fb24443-1476-e911-a975-000d3ab0fc6e"
            },
            {
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"1445929\"",
                "fullname": "Portal Customer",
                "contactid": "99db51a2-c34e-e111-bb8d-00155d03a715"
            },
            {
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"1445935\"",
                "fullname": "System Administrator",
                "contactid": "7469fd95-c0bd-4236-90bf-1d1100291df5"
            },
            {
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"1668674\"",
                "fullname": "Vincent Lauriant",
                "contactid": "465b158c-541c-e511-80d3-3863bb347ba8"
            },
            {
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"1437642\"",
                "fullname": "Adrian Dumitrascu",
                "contactid": "49a0e5b9-88df-e311-b8e5-6c3be5a8b200"
            },
            {
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"1667039\"",
                "fullname": "Cathan Cook",
                "contactid": "4ba0e5b9-88df-e311-b8e5-6c3be5a8b200"
            },
```

Explanation for 5k Records is availabel in Microsodt Docs

> Specify the number of entities to return in a page Use the
>   odata.maxpagesize preference value to request the number of entities
>   returned in the response.
>
> Note
>
> You can’t use an odata.maxpagesize preference value greater than 5000.

```
    Request
        GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$select=name HTTP/1.1  
        Accept: application/json  
        OData-MaxVersion: 4.0  
        OData-Version: 4.0  
        Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=3 

Response
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
    Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal  
    OData-Version: 4.0  
    Content-Length: 402  
    Preference-Applied: odata.maxpagesize=3  

    {  
       "@odata.context":"[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#accounts(name)",
       "value":[  
          {  
             "@odata.etag":"W/\"437194\"",
             "name":"Fourth Coffee (sample)",
             "accountid":"7d51925c-cde2-e411-80db-00155d2a68cb"
          },
          {  
             "@odata.etag":"W/\"437195\"",
             "name":"Litware, Inc. (sample)",
             "accountid":"7f51925c-cde2-e411-80db-00155d2a68cb"
          },
          {  
             "@odata.etag":"W/\"468026\"",
             "name":"Adventure Works (sample)",
             "accountid":"8151925c-cde2-e411-80db-00155d2a68cb"
          }
       ],
       "@odata.nextLink":"[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$select=name&$skiptoken=%3Ccookie%20pagenumber=%222%22%20pagingcookie=%22%253ccookie%2520page%253d%25221%2522%253e%253caccountid%2520last%253d%2522%257b8151925C-CDE2-E411-80DB-00155D2A68CB%257d%2522%2520first%253d%2522%257b7D51925C-CDE2-E411-80DB-00155D2A68CB%257d%2522%2520%252f%253e%253c%252fcookie%253e%22%20/%3E"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks AnkUser. You provided me a key to help solve the puzzle. Instead of using PHP and cURL which our application is built in, I used a REST tool called Insomnia and found the difference. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. It would be cool if you mark this answer as solved. Will help others as well

Comment: Stackover flow gives me message "You can accept your answer tomorrow". I'll have to loop back around and mark it solved. Thanks for the suggestion.